# Jave beginner - count number of words in a string

Tags: java

I'm trying to write code that receives a string as input and then counts the number of words within said string, but it returns 1 no matter the input. Surprisingly, pasting the sample code from my textbook (C. Thomas Wu - An Introduction to Object-Oriented Programming) gives the same problem and I can't figure out why.

My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a sentence: ");
        String sentence = scanner.next();
        char BLANK = ' ';
        int index = 0, wordCount = 0;
        int numberOfCharacters = sentence.length();
        while (index < sentence.length()){
            while (index < sentence.length() && sentence.charAt(index) != BLANK){
                index++;
            }
            while (index < sentence.length() && sentence.charAt(index) == BLANK){
                index++;
            }
            wordCount++;
        }
        System.out.println(wordCount);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you mean [`scanner.nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())?

Comment: oops, didn't realise that i had been using ```scanner.next()``` all along. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used `scanner.next()` which will capture only the first word of the sentence. It stops where it finds a white space. You need to use `scanner.nextLine()`.

Also, given below is another way of doing it:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
        System.out.println("Total no. of words: " + scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+").length);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter a sentence: Ram is a good boy.
Total no. of words: 5
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter a sentence: Harry is an                 intelligent           guy.
Total no. of words: 5
```

In this program, we are splitting the input on space(s) using `String::split` function, which returns a `String[]` with the words of the input as its elements, and then we are printing the length of this resulting `String[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner.next returns only a single "word" (for some definition of word), and every time you call it will return the next word in the input.

To get an entire line of text, with multiple words, use `nextLine`:

```
    String sentence = scanner.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can do this by using `sentence.split(' ')` and getting the length.

For an example:

```java
    String sentence = "I like eating apples everyday";
    String[] words = sentence.split(' ');

    int wordCount = words.length;
```

Comment: also using nextLine() will get the whole text entered rather than just the word (see other answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to count all types of spaces including more than 1 successive space characters, tabs & line returns:

`\\s is` a regex that matches space characters

`.split():` split the string into different strings based on a separator/delimiter which is the `\\s+` regex

```
    String sentence = scanner.next();
    String[] split= sentence.split("\\s+");
    int wordCount = split.length;
    System.out.println(wordCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

Code to check count number of words in a string:

```java
String sentence = "I'm new user of Java!";

int word_count = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < sentence.length(); i++) { 
     char ch = sentence.charAt(i);
     char ch2 = sentence.charAt(i-1);

     if (ch == ' ' && ch2 != ' ')
        word_count++;
} 

System.out.println("Word count: " + word_count);
```

out:
`Word count: 4`

[java code at online compilier](https://techiedelight.com/compiler/?~kmwordcount)